# Camel - Stop route when the consuming directory not exists

Tags: apache-camel

I've an SFTP route (in Spring XML), and its from path ends in a daily changing directory (ie. /yyyyMMdd), and everything is working well when `autoCreate=true` or the directory exists when the route starts. But it is not permitted to me to create the directory if not exists!

When the dir exists, the route get files and terminates itself.

When the dir not exists, the route is polling permanently with a warning (ie. `org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot change directory to: 20160917`) and never stops.

How can I avoid this behaviour (eg. convert the warning to an empty message or exception or ...)? I've done experiments with startingDirectoryMustExist, consumer.bridgeErrorHandler and many others without any success.

The simplified route (before start, fill the elmu.sftp.importDir property with the actual date):

```
    <from
        uri="sftp://{{elmu.sftp.host}}:{{elmu.sftp.port}}{{elmu.sftp.importDir}}?username={{elmu.sftp.userName}}&amp;password={{elmu.sftp.password}}&amp;
        autoCreate=false&amp;preferredAuthentications=password&amp;binary=true&amp;include={{elmu.importMask}}&amp;initialDelay=100&amp;
        noop=true&amp;sortBy=file:name&amp;sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true"/>
    <choice>
        <when>
            <simple>${body} != null</simple>
            ... a lot of stuff ...
            <to uri="bean:shutdownRoute" />
        </when>
        <otherwise>
            <to uri="bean:shutdownRoute" />
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
```

With `directoryMustExist=true and startingDirectoryMustExist=true` the result is an endless loop (poll) with this warning:

```
08:30:14,658 WARN  SftpConsumer - Consumer Consumer[sftp://xxx.xxx.xx:22/DBHtest/ELMUteszt/Kiadott_adatok/20160918?autoCreate=false&binary=true&directoryMustExist=true&include=%5E.*%24&initialDelay=100&noop=true&password=xxxxxx&preferredAuthentications=password&sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true&sortBy=file%3Aname&startingDirectoryMustExist=true&username=xxx] failed polling endpoint: Endpoint[sftp://xxx:22/DBHtest/ELMUteszt/Kiadott_adatok/20160918?autoCreate=false&binary=true&directoryMustExist=true&include=%5E.*%24&initialDelay=100&noop=true&password=xxxxxx&preferredAuthentications=password&sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true&sortBy=file%3Aname&startingDirectoryMustExist=true&username=xxx]. Will try again at next poll. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException - Cannot change directory to: 20160918] 
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot change directory to: 20160918
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.doChangeDirectory(SftpOperations.java:576)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.changeCurrentDirectory(SftpOperations.java:564)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer.doPollDirectory(SftpConsumer.java:107)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpConsumer.pollDirectory(SftpConsumer.java:79)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileConsumer.poll(GenericFileConsumer.java:131)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.doRun(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:175)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.ScheduledPollConsumer.run(ScheduledPollConsumer.java:102)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: 2: No such file
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.throwStatusError(ChannelSftp.java:2846)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp._realpath(ChannelSftp.java:2340)
    at com.jcraft.jsch.ChannelSftp.cd(ChannelSftp.java:342)
    at org.apache.camel.component.file.remote.SftpOperations.doChangeDirectory(SftpOperations.java:574)
    ... 13 more
```

It doesn't work with `stepwise=false`:

```
11:52:19,210 WARN  SftpConsumer - Consumer Consumer[sftp://xxx:22/DBHtest/ELMUteszt/Kiadott_adatok/20160918?autoCreate=false&binary=true&directoryMustExist=true&include=%5E.*%24&initialDelay=100&noop=true&password=xxxxxx&preferredAuthentications=password&sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true&sortBy=file%3Aname&startingDirectoryMustExist=true&stepwise=false&username=xxx] failed polling endpoint: Endpoint[sftp://xxx:22/DBHtest/ELMUteszt/Kiadott_adatok/20160918?autoCreate=false&binary=true&directoryMustExist=true&include=%5E.*%24&initialDelay=100&noop=true&password=xxxxxx&preferredAuthentications=password&sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true&sortBy=file%3Aname&startingDirectoryMustExist=true&stepwise=false&username=xxx]. Will try again at next poll. Caused by: [org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException - Cannot list directory: DBHtest/ELMUteszt/Kiadott_adatok/20160918] 
org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot list directory: DBHtest/ELMUteszt/Kiadott_adatok/20160918
```

UPDATE (according to @ruffp's answer):

I've tried to set up a custom PollingConsumerPollStrategy, but I cannot stop the route from it. Only the third (commented row) stops the route, but I've several routes and I cannot know the name of the actual route. How can I get it?

```
    @Override
    public boolean rollback(Consumer consumer, Endpoint endpoint, int retryCounter, Exception cause) throws Exception {
        consumer.getEndpoint().stop(); // 1
        consumer.stop();  // 2
        consumer.getEndpoint().getCamelContext().stopRoute(route???);  // 3
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your route as it is?

Comment: I've shared the route.

Comment: Have you tried adding directoryMustExist=true and startingDirectoryMustExist=true? After adding them, can you show the log output you get?

Comment: guess you need to handle exceptions for soft terminating

Comment: @Souciance Eqdam Rashti: I've posted the output.

Comment: @Pat: There is onException, but nothing to catch because there is no exception.

Comment: I would add stepwise=false as well. I tseems it is trying to do a cd to that folder but since the folder does not exist it gives warn. Can you add this param and post the log output again? I suspect this is the main issue. If it works I can add it as an answer.

Comment: @Souciance Eqdam Rashti: Posted. No success. The new warning "cannot list" instead of "cannot change".

Comment: Are you sure your user has the right permissions to do basic file operations? Your user should be able to list directories.

Comment: Yes, of course. As I mentioned it's working well with autocreate so it has more rights than enough. The user can do anything, I've tried with sftp programs.

Comment: If I understand well, you just want to treat the exception when the directory is not existing?

Comment: Yes, it would be a good solution. But an empty message would be the greatest :-).

Comment: What do you want to happen if the FTP directory do not exists? Should Camel then stop the route, and then you would have to manually start the route to try again? And what level of logging should Camel do in such situation?

Comment: @Claus Ibsen: An option to generate an empty message, exception, stop the route or anything else would be great, just not to poll again with a warning. My task is to download files, on-demand, if there any (on the daily directory) and stop. If no files or directory at all, just stop. The logging is almost indifferent for me, if the not existing directory is treated as "no files". Thanks!

Comment: According to your latest updates: did you try just to return false (without the other code)? or perhaps to re-throw the GenericFileOperationFailedException so that you can catch it in the onException() route?

Comment: Yes, of course. There is nothing to catch, polling endless with the usual warning. There is no difference between just return false or re-throw, the camel catch the exception and convert it to a warning, and poll again. I've tried to throw other types of exceptions (new ones), but all converted to warning so I cannot catch. It seems the only working way to stop the route using the CamelContext, but in the real case I do not know the routeid and do not know how to get it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I've solved it with `consumer.exceptionHandler`. But it seems, that **this option is not in list of the usable options** (http://camel.apache.org/file2.html which I've been reading again and again) just mentioned once with an example at the bottom of the huge page. Unfortunately, it was so "hidden" that I missed it up to now.

I set up a new class and implemented the handleExceptions methods:

```
public class DirNotExistsExHandler implements ExceptionHandler
```

which get the exceptions and decide what to do. In the context, I did a bean definition:

```
<bean id="dirNotExistsExHandler" class="hu.dbit.eleo.DirNotExistsExHandler" />
```

And in the consumer, passed the bean to the handler:

```
consumer.exceptionHandler=#dirNotExistsExHandler
```

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion the best way to do it would be:

1. Enable the option `throwExceptionOnConnectFailed` on the `sftp` endpoint like this:

   ```
   sftp://{{elmu.sftp.host}}:{{elmu.sftp.port}}{{elmu.sftp.importDir}}?username={{elmu.sftp.userName}}&amp;password={{elmu.sftp.password}}&amp;
   autoCreate=false&amp;preferredAuthentications=password&amp;binary=true&amp;include={{elmu.importMask}}&amp;initialDelay=100&amp;
   noop=true&amp;sortBy=file:name&amp;sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true&amp;throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true
   ```

   This could help to manage with the exception and to be catch it by the camel routes onException. However I am not sure it is really necessary in your case.
2. Make a special processing for your connection exception

   ```
   // 2a) Solution to redirect an empty body to a destination
   onException(GenericFileOperationFailedException.class)
               .handled(true)
               .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Source directory not present: send empty body to shutdown route...")
               .setBody(null)
               .to("bean:shutdownRoute");
   ```

   Or another way:

   ```
   // 2b)Solution to just stop the processing without log in warn or error
   onException(GenericFileOperationFailedException.class)
       .handled(true)
       .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "Source directory not present: stop the process and wait until next time...")
       .stop();
   ```

UPDATE:
I found [this post](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Apache-Camel-onException-does-not-get-fired-td4899276.html) and apparently there is not another way than implementing your own `PollingConsumerPollStrategy` because the `GenericFileOperationFailedException` is apparently handled inside the default implementation.

Comment: Thank you, but unfortunately it doesn't work, because there is no exception (on the route level). I think, the camel "catch and translate" the exception to warning even `throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true`.

Comment: I've read your edited post, and it seems that it's possible way to achieve my goal. But unfortunately, it seems very difficult (and overwhelmed, if I may say) and I don't know how to start to implement it in xml (spring). But I'm trying to manage it. Thank you!

Comment: I've updated my original question, please have a look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Handle the exception using doCatch block. If no exception is thrown then check file exists using your code and throw exception manually.

http://camel.apache.org/try-catch-finally.html

Comment: Sorry, but I do not understand you. Could you be more specific? How to check (and what file) existence on the sftp? My problem again: I have to download all files, and terminate. But when the directory (the full path with a daily directory on the end) not exists, just terminate.

Comment: I suppose when the file is not present at destination, some exception is thrown like FileNotFoundException. So, just catch that exception and the route will get terminated

Comment: In your case, use :
          <doCatch>
            <exception>GenericFileOperationFailedException</exception>
        </doCatch>

Comment: I do not know any exact file name to download, I just have a mask. And as I mentioned there is no exception at all so nothing to catch. Only a warning which cannot be caught.

Answer (score 0):

Otto Csatari: To get Route Id of failed route in rollback method use below code snipped

```
    CamelContext context = endpoint.getCamelContext();
    List<Route> routes = context.getRoutes();
    SftpEndpoint sftpEndpoint = (SftpEndpoint)endpoint;
    Route failedRoute =  routes.stream().filter(route -> ((SftpEndpoint) route.getEndpoint())
            .getConfiguration().getDirectoryName().equals(sftpEndpoint.getConfiguration().getDirectoryName()))
            .findAny().orElse(null);
```