# File component's [consumer.]bridgeErrorHandler in conjunction with startingDirectoryMustExist

Tags: exception, apache-camel

I have a route (with Camel 2.23.1) like:

```
from("file://not.existing.dir?autoCreate=false&startingDirectoryMustExist=true&consumer.bridgeErrorHandler=true")

    .onException(Exception.class)
    .handled(true)
    .log(LoggingLevel.ERROR, "...exception text...")
    .end()

    .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, "...process text...")

    ...
```

(I tried it with just `&bridgeErrorHandler`, too, since [according to the latest doc](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/docs/components/modules/ROOT/pages/file-component.adoc#user-content-query-parameters-87-parameters) the `consumer.` prefix seems to be not necessary any longer.)

According to [the doc of `startingDirectoryMustExist`](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/docs/components/modules/ROOT/pages/file-component.adoc):

> |   **startingDirectoryMustExist**   |   [...] Will thrown an exception if the directory doesn’t exist.   |

the following exception is thrown:

```
org.apache.camel.FailedToCreateRouteException: Failed to create route route1:
  Route(route1)[[From[file://not.existing.dir?autoCreate=false...
  because of Starting directory does not exist: not.existing.dir
...
```

but, despite of [the doc](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/docs/components/modules/ROOT/pages/file-component.adoc#user-content-query-parameters-87-parameters) and the [description of `[consumer.]bridgeErrorHandler`](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/docs/components/modules/ROOT/pages/file-component.adoc#user-content-using-consumerbridgeerrorhandler) *it's propagated to the caller*, i.e neither "`exception text`" nor "`process text`" are printed.

There is [a unit test `FileConsumerBridgeRouteExceptionHandlerTest` that covers `consumer.bridgeErrorHandler`](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/core/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/file/FileConsumerBridgeRouteExceptionHandlerTest.java#L61), so I think this works basically. Can it be that `[consumer.]bridgeErrorHandler` doesn't work in conjunction with the exception thrown by `startingDirectoryMustExist`?

Do I have to write my own `[consumer.]exceptionHandler` as mentioned in [this answer to "*Camel - Stop route when the consuming directory not exists*"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39609198/1744774)?

There also a [post on the mailing list from 2014](http://camel.465427.n5.nabble.com/Issue-in-FILE-consumer-URI-having-startingDirectoryMustExist-set-to-true-td5759521.html) that reports similar behaviour with `startingDirectoryMustExist` and `consumer.bridgeErrorHandler`.

#### UPDATE

After TRACEing and debugging through the code I found that the exception is propagated as follows:

```
FileEndpoint.createConsumer()
  throw new FileNotFoundException(...);
--> RouteService.warmUp()
      throw new FailedToCreateRouteException(...)
    --> DefaultCamelContext.doStart()
          (re)throw e
        --> ServiceSupport.start()
              (re)throw e
```

I couldn't find any point where `bridgeErrorHandler` comes into play.

Setting breakpoints on [`BridgeExceptionHandlerToErrorHandler`](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/release/2.23.1/camel-core/src/main/java/org/apache/camel/impl/BridgeExceptionHandlerToErrorHandler.java)'s constructor and all of its `handleException()` methods doesn't stop at any of them.

Am I still missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `directoryMustExist` option instead, then you can have the error during polling, which is where the bridge error handler can be triggered. The `startingDirectoryMustExist` option is checked during creating the consumer and therefore before the polling and where the bridge error handler operates.

See also the JIRA ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-13174

Comment: Using `directoryMustExist` in the code I presented in the JIRA, no exception is thrown (no corresponding log message), `onException()` isn't executed (of course, there's no exception), the route is started (`... INFO  DefaultCamelContext – Route: route2 started and consuming from: file://not.existing.dir?autoCreate=false&bridgeErrorHandler=true&directoryMustExist=true`) but it's doing nothing ("`... processing ...`" isn't logged) even if I add `&sendEmptyMessageWhenIdle=true`. `BridgeExceptionHandlerToErrorHandler` is instantiated twice but none if its `handleException()` methods is called.

Comment: See this unit test: https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/core/camel-core/src/test/java/org/apache/camel/component/file/FileConsumerDirectoryMustExistBridgeErrorHandlerTest.java

Comment: The test fails if I replace `errorHandler(deadLetterChannel("mock:dead"));` with a route scope`.onException(Exception.class).to("mock:dead")`. It succeeds (with an according error log msg, contrary to `errorHandler()`) using a global scope `onException()`. Apparently that means that I always have to use `.errorHandler()` or a global scope `onException()` in combination with a route scope `onException()` to cover all error cases, right? I always thought that the scope is the (only) difference and trigger conditions are the same. That's at least what I read from the docs.

Comment: you need to have handled(true) in your onexception block

Comment: I see. It works with that now. I interpreted ["should be marked as handled or not" in the Javadoc](https://static.javadoc.io/org.apache.camel/camel-core/2.23.1/org/apache/camel/model/OnExceptionDefinition.html) as informational (for subsequent processes), not as functional prerequisite (for the error-handling process itself).